# JavaScript: how to fix Uncaught Refrence Error?

Tags: javascript

I have learnt that whenever we don't define a variable and only initialize it in a function then it is treated as global variable. Also I have learnt that variable is always defined first at the time the program starts to run.

```
var globalVariable = "This is a global variable";

function fun(){
localVariable = "This is a local Varible";
console.log();
console.log();

}

console.log(localVariable);//This is a local Varible(Ouput)
console.log(globalVariable);//This is a global variable(Output)
```

The above code seems to be working fine but I am confused by seeing the output of the below code, I am trying to clear my concepts.

```
var globalVariable = "This is a global variable"
function fun(){
console.log(localVariable); //Uncaught ReferenceError: localVariable is not defined

localVariable = "This is a local Varible";

}
fun();

console.log(globalVariable);//This is a global variable(Output)
```

I am not sure why console.log(localVariable); is giving Uncaught Refrence Error

Comment: you are using it before initializing it

Comment: Your `localVariable ` is NOT a local variable.

Comment: huh? because localVariable is literally not yet defined.

Comment: "whenever we don't define a variable and only initialize it in a function then it is treated as global variable" - It's a ReferenceError for any sane person, those who write in strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has been said by others about the scope of your variables is correct, but I would like to add one thing.

> "I have learnt that variable is always defined first at the time the program starts to run."

I think this may have caused confusion in you,
JavaScript use hoisting. The parser read through the entire function and execute any variable declarations as if is at the begin of the scope.
But you have to declare it using the var keyword, currently you are only assigning it a value.

This, for example, works, despite the declaration is subsequent to the use of the variable

```
x = 5; 
elem = document.getElementById("demo"); 
elem.innerHTML = x;                    
var x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it is working - note the `var` inside the function

```js
var globalVariable = "This is a global variable"

function fun() {

  var localVariable = "NOW this is a local Variable";

  console.log(localVariable); //now this is a local variable

}
fun(); 

console.log(globalVariable); //This is a global variable(Output)
```

Comment: what is the different between this answer and the question?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay: one `var`

Comment: he is not initialized local variable

Comment: Your answer is WRONG. Period. @Manesh

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay: could you elaborate? This code does not crash with a ReferenceError.

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay explain what your problem with the code is?

Comment: if its only concerning the error then thats fine. my thoughts were focused at it getting the desired output. apologies. indeed this is correct in reference to the question

Answer (score 0):

Simple in order to view the log of any variable you do require to define it first.

```js
var globalVariable = "This is a global variable"
function fun(){

var localVariable = "This is a local Varible";
console.log(localVariable); //Uncaught ReferenceError: localVariable is not defined

}
fun();

console.log(globalVariable);//This is a global variable(Output)
```

JavaScript variables are containers for storing data values. All JavaScript variables must be identified with unique names. These unique names are called identifiers. So first you do require to tell which identifier represent what then only you can view the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variables defined in a function are not global, they are local.

I think you may be calling localVariable before it is defined. Define it firat and then do console.log().

Comment: if you don't use var to declare a variable in a function, as op has done in their code, then it is global